# Create a comparative table from a df in R

Tags: r, dataframe, boolean

I have a data frame with a set of gene names as rows and gene characteristics as columns. My idea is to create a comparative table with Boolean values indicating whether they match for a one or lots of characteristics.

As an example I create the following recreating the expected result

First here I create a list of personal characteristics with people names. In my real data they are gene characteristics with gene names in them.

```
Gentle <- as.character(c("Jhon", "Louis", "Mark"))
Mean <- as.character(c("Jhon", "German", "Jesse"))
Cool <- as.character(c("Louis", "Jack", "Jesse"))
Naive <- as.character(c("Walter", "German", "Mark"))
```

This is the example of the df I already have, my input data.

```
df <- data.frame(Gentle, Mean, Cool, Naive)
```

And here what I'm expecting to get, where the subject names (gene names) have a Boolen value, obtaining a comparative table.

```
result <- data.frame(Gentle = c(T,T,T,F,F,F,F), Mean = c(T,F,F,T,T,F,F),
                     Cool=c(F,T,F,F,T,T,F), Naive = c(F,F,T,T,F,F,T))
rownames(result) <- as.character(c("Jhon", "Louis", "Mark", "German", "Jesse", "Jack","Walter"))
colnames(result) <- as.character(c("Gentle", "Mean", "Cool", "Naive"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get `unique` names from dataframe,use `sapply` to loop over each column and use `table` to get their presence/absence.

```
unique_name <- unique(unlist(df))
sapply(df, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = unique_name)) > 0)

#       Gentle  Mean  Cool Naive
#Jhon     TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#Louis    TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#Mark     TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#German  FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#Jesse   FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#Jack    FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#Walter  FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `table` on `stack`

```
table(stack(df)) > 0
#       ind
#values   Gentle  Mean  Cool Naive
#  German  FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#  Jack    FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#  Jesse   FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#  Jhon     TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#  Louis    TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#  Mark     TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#  Walter  FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

Or using `pivot_longer/pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, everything()) %>% 
   dplyr::count(name, value) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = n, 
     values_fn = list(n = ~length(.) > 0), values_fill = list(n = FALSE))
```